# How to change background using conditions and save it in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a code that changes text when the button is clicked:

```
// New Game route
class NewGameRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewGameRoute({key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'New Game',
      home: ListFromCSV1(),
    );
  }
}

class ListFromCSV1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState1 createState() => _ListFromCSVState1();
}

class _ListFromCSVState1 extends State<ListFromCSV1> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;

  @override
  initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(_rawData);
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad ? _isFirstLoad = false
          : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('files/main.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('files/sheet.jpg'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    // onPressed: () {},
                    onPressed: _nextCSV,

                    child: const Text('OK'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    // onPressed: _nextCSV,

                    child: const Text('Hide'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to do the same for pictures used as backgrounds. But there is a certain condition.

1. By default, my user should see the picture that is specified in the code:

   image: AssetImage('files/main.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
2. Next, my user must click on the OK button and there are two options:
   2.1 If _listData[_listCount](https://mega.nz/file/I1h3GKRZ#LWmYoe0XhUMZHSOmCW87xRI_X3_m-4MMJ3vwS7tdkeE) is empty, then the picture does not change.
   2.2. If _listData[_listCount](https://mega.nz/file/I1h3GKRZ#LWmYoe0XhUMZHSOmCW87xRI_X3_m-4MMJ3vwS7tdkeE) is not empty (for example, images/02.jpg), then the user should see this picture.
3. The path to the image my user sees should be saved so that the next time my user opens this app, he/she will see it.

Here is a small file for testing: [FILE](https://mega.nz/file/I1h3GKRZ#LWmYoe0XhUMZHSOmCW87xRI_X3_m-4MMJ3vwS7tdkeE)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the images url in the sheet are predefined in assets or from using network path?

Comment: All the pictures are in assets (in the picture folder). Like files/main.jpg, files/01.jpg, files/02.jpg and so on.

Comment: do you have any screen for expected result?

Comment: There is a main menu. Next, I click on the "New Game" button and I get to the screen with the code shown here.

Comment: this is not clear. without a proper explanation for the problem, it'll be difficult to solve your issue.

Comment: I am ready to give any explanation. I am a newbie so I just don't understand some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
class ListFromCSV extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListFromCSV({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListFromCSVState createState() => _ListFromCSVState();
}

class _ListFromCSVState extends State<ListFromCSV> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _listData = [
    [""]
  ];
  int _listCount = 0;
  bool _isFirstLoad = true;
  String assetPath = "assets/files/main.jpeg";

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCSV();
  }

  // This function is only triggered at init, so we only load csv once
  void _loadCSV() async {
    String rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/files/Text.csv");
    _listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? "assets/files/main.jpeg" : _listData[_listCount][1];
  }

  // This function is triggered when my button is pressed
  void _nextCSV() {
    setState(() {
      _listData = _listData;
      _listCount < _listData.length - 1
          ? _isFirstLoad
              ? _isFirstLoad = false
              : _listCount++
          : _listCount;
      assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Game'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/files/sheet.jpeg"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(assetPath),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(_listData[_listCount][0]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    // onPressed: () {},
                    onPressed: _nextCSV,
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    // onPressed: _nextCSV,
                    child: const Text('Hide'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do not forget to add the images pubsec.yaml file and in CSV mention the correct path.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, except for one thing. I want that if there is no path to a new image in the csv file, my user will see the previous one and not main.jpg

I mean, in this code, instead of files/main.jpg, there should be something else:

assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? "files/main.jpg" : _listData[_listCount][1];

Comment: change this line in nextCSV method.   assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1]; in that method alone

Comment: edited the answer as well

Comment: Yes, thank you. Everything is exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add condition in the AssetImage like isListEmpty then it should be like this, and images/02.jpg in asset folder already.
Use Shared Ppreferences to store that in local maybe

```
AssetImage( isListEmpty ? 'files/main.jpg' : 'images/02.jpg')
```

Comment: I mean, if this row is empty, then I don't need to change the path to the file and show the file that was shown before. That is, it is not 02.jpg, but the one that is shown at the moment. I am probably explaining it confusingly. I don't know how to do it, to be honest.

Comment: as i understand now. You want the background in 2 conditions: if _listData empty: show 1 picture, if _listData is NOT empty: show 2nd picture?

Comment: As Prabhakaran wrote, it will look like this: assetPath = _listData[_listCount][1] == "" ? assetPath : _listData[_listCount][1]; Nevertheless, thanks for your attention to my question.